# Calling a function inside submit button

Tags: jquery, submit

i am trying call the function notEmpty inside another function validateForm. But i need pass the selector for this function and after submit the form.

Take a look:

```
$("#accountemail").blur(notEmpty);
$("#submit_account").click(validateForm);

function notEmpty()
{
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        // Send a warning message
        warn($(this), "notEmpty");
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        // Remove a warning message
        unwarn($(this), "notEmpty");
        return true;
    }
}

function validateForm()
{   
    // How i can call the function passing the selector and after submit the form?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument to your validateForm function. WHen you pass the function name as argument to clcik handler jQuery will return the element within your function

```
    $("#submit_account").click(validateForm);

function validateForm()

{   

     /* $(this) will be the same as $("#submit_account")*/
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `element` contain the event object and not the element in your first snippet?

Comment: you can be more precise? i tried $("#accountemail").notEmpty(); but doens't work

Comment: @KillCloud you are trying to treat function as a plugin , which it is not. So you can't chain method to selector. Make a demo in jsfiddle.net